# Media volume resetting every time while opening the activity

Tags: android, jwplayer

I am using jwplayer to play the video in activity and also setting mute and un mute options.
While starting the activity every time the device volume is setting to zero. i am raising the device volume every time to listen the audio

I am using the following code to  play video

PlaylistItem pi = new PlaylistItem.Builder()
                .file(url)
               .title("Swan")
                .image(thumbnailURL ")

```
            .build();
    single_video_vv.load(pi);

    single_video_vv.play();

    single_video_vv.addOnCompleteListener(new VideoPlayerEvents.OnCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(CompleteEvent completeEvent) {


        }
    });


    single_video_vv.addOnReadyListener(new VideoPlayerEvents.OnReadyListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReady(ReadyEvent readyEvent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onReady() called with: readyEvent = [" + readyEvent.toString() + "]");
        }
    });

    single_video_vv.addOnPlayListener(new VideoPlayerEvents.OnPlayListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlay(PlayEvent playEvent) {

        }
    });
    single_video_vv.addOnErrorListener(new VideoPlayerEvents.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onError(ErrorEvent errorEvent) {

        }
    });
    single_video_vv.play();
```

try {
            if (mute) {

```
            single_video_vv.setMute(true);
        } else {
 single_video_vv.setMute(false);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Everytime new object will be created while activity launch so everytime it will start from scratch. You need to save in shared preference if you want to previous volume

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you

Comment: every time i am playing different videos